# Filtering out empty Optionals

Tags: java, stream, null, optional

I want to convert my list of optional strings to a list of strings by getting rid of the empty `Optional`s.

Is there a shorter version for achieving this than the following code (except statically importing the methods of `Collectors`)?

```
List<Optional<String>> stringsMaybe = Arrays.asList(Optional.of("Hi"),
                                      Optional.empty(), Optional.of(" there!"));

List<String> strings = stringsMaybe
            .stream()
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .collect(Collectors.mapping(Optional::get, Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's more idiomatic to use `.map` on the stream instead of `Collectors.mapping`:

```
stringsMaybe.stream()
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .collect(toList());
```

Without introducing a helper method or a custom collector, that's the shortest and clearest way to do this.

Since Java 9, `Optional` offers a [`stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--) method, enabling you to do `.flatMap(Optional::stream)` instead of `.filter(...).map(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using rxJava you can do something like:

```
Flux<Optional<String>> maybeStrings = Flux.just(
    Optional.of("Hi"),
    Optional.empty(),
    Optional.of(" there!"));

Flux<String> strings = maybeStrings.handle((maybeString, synchronousSink) -> 
    maybeString.ifPresent(synchronousSink::next));
```

Comment: Hi, on CodeReview it's expected to explain why your solution offers a better alternative than the current code :)

Comment: The only reason you'd want to use my example instead of the selected answer is if you're operating on a rxJava Flux rather than a Java 8 Stream. Technically this does not answer the question but someone searching for this example may benefit from this snippet none the less.